# Inequality with derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

does somebody know this inequality:
$\|Df\|^2\le C(\|f\|\|D^2f\|+\|f\|^2)$.
(The Norm is defined by $\|f\|^2=\int_a^b\int_c^df(x,y)^2dxdy$).

I guess that it can be proved by some sort of integration by parts. But probably there is some name for this, that would make the problem easier. :)

Thanks in advance